# A basic problem on expectation

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose for a non-negative random variable $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(X \geq t) dt= \infty$ I need to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geq na) = \infty$ for each $a$. How to go from continuous case to discrete case here ?

Answer (score 3):

For $a > 0$ (other cases are trivial)
It follows from $$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq t \big) \, dt = \infty $$
that
$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq at \big) \, dt = \infty \,\, . $$

Then $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq at \big) \, dt = \infty \,\, . $$
Clearly $\mathbb{P}\big(  X \geq n a \big)\geq \mathbb{P}\big(  X \geq (n+1) a \big)$, then we have $$ \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq an \big) \geq  \int_{n}^{n+1}\mathbb{P}\big( X \geq at \big) \, dt$$
hence
$$  \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq an \big) \geq         \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}\big( X \geq at \big) \, dt = \infty \,\, . $$